# Is it possible to access an IB object (say, a UILabel) without declaring a IBOutlet property?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, nib, iboutlet

I have more than 20 labels that I need to update at runtime, and I was wondering if it could be possible to access them without having to declare properties and outlets for all of them. I tried to assign a unique tag to each, and access them trhough the view in my view contoller, something like this:

```
 self.view.myLabel1.text = @"Some text";
```

But it did not work. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The tag-approach is the right one, but you have to access the labels differently. Assuming `self.view` is the parent view of the labels and all labels have an unique tag (integer), you can get them like this:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example of 'setting' the text for a UILabel with a tag?

Comment: After getting the label object, just assign a value to its `text` property:
`label.text = @"My Text";`

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know Xcode does not know nothing about your xib UIElements if you don't declare them.
I had similar dilemma long time ago, and since then, when i have a large number of objects from the same kind i prefer to make them reusable by creating them programmatically.

good luck